# Deletion of service name in Zipkin dropdown list

Tags: zipkin

I have the following problem: i have added numerous services in Zipkin but now i want to remove some of them. I keep the data in memory so no persistency involved there.
Is there any way to delete a service name from Zipkin's service name dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to remove the spring.zipkin.base-url property from the corresponding applications to remove it from zipkin server list.

Answer (score 0):

I think to remove the service names from zipkin you have to Re-deploy the zipkin service